# Filtering SQL rows by DateTime interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 with millions of logs which we need to filter down in a stored procedure. Each log has a `LogTime` field which I will be using for this filtering. I want to only return logs that are more than 15 minutes apart, skipping the ones that are too close to each other in terms of `LogTime`.

The logs are generally within seconds of each other so this time interval will limit the logs appropriately. I also don't care about skipping most of the log items. It also doesn't matter if the interval between logs is greater than 15 minutes if the next log is hours away, as long as the interval is at least 15 minutes.

So for instance the first log was at 15:30, skip all the logs until 15:45. Find the next log at 15:46 and carry on like that.

Example of the output I need:

```
15:30 - Log Content
15:46 - Log Content
16:12 - Log Content
18:00 - Log Content
```

I've been searching and trying all sorts of stuff through trial and error. Unfortunately my SQL knowledge doesn't stretch very far and I've been unable to create a solution that runs in any decent timeframe.

Comment: We were unable to find a satisfactory SQL solution to our problem so we used a combined strategy of chunking the requests to the DB and then filtering on the server before requesting the next chunk.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

As you have described the problem, it is going to be quite computationally expensive.  You can solve it using a recursive CTE or cursor.  Either method will take a long time.

There are two alternatives.  The first is to truncate each of the date/times to a 15 minute interval and then pull the first one.  You can do this using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(logtime as date), datepart(hour, logtime), datepart(minute, logtime) / 4
                                order by logtime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

An alternative method is to take the first in sequence when there is a gap of 15 minutes or more.  For this, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(logtime) over (order by logtime) as prev_logtime
      from t
     ) t
where logtime > dateadd(minute, 15, prev_logtime) or prev_logtime is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = 1,
        LogTime = MIN(LogTime)
        FROM LogTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SeqNo = SeqNo+1,
        LogTime = DATEADD(MINUTE,15,LogTime)
        FROM CTE
            WHERE LogTime < GETDATE()
            OR SeqNo < 100
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM LogTable LT
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM CTE WHERE LogTime = LT.LogTime
        )
```

this will display all records from the starting of the log table with the interval of 15 minutes. Till for 100 distinct times slots or Time rea ches current time, which ever is first

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is to use a query that looks something like this which gets the previous time for each record and computes the number of minutes between them.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE DateDiff(mi, (SELECT TOP 1 LogTime FROM YourTable as sub 
  WHERE YourTable.LogTime > sub.LogTime ORDER BY LogTime DESC), LogTime) > 15
```